# ¿Porque la propiedad sort de MatTable me aparece como udenfinied?

Tags: angular, ordenamiento, material, mat-table, sortable

Estoy trabajando con una tabla de Angular Material, pero cuando defino la variable:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true})
  sort: MatSort = new MatSort();
```

Para posteriormente usarla en este metodo de ordenamiento

```
public sortController(event: any): void {
    console.log('Controller inside....')
    this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({ id: '', }) as MatSortable);
    switch (event) {
      case 'recent':
        this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({ id: 'date', start: 'desc' }) as MatSortable);
        break;
      case 'old':
        this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({ id: 'date', start: 'asc' }) as MatSortable);
        break;
    }
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Me sale el error que se aprecia en la imagen, me pueden decir ¿por qué la variable sort esta undefinied? Si incluso la inicialice al principio de mi código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Falta información, no puedo cuando llamas al sortController o cuando defines,  this.dataSource. Me puedes decir que linea es la 57 de separate.component.ts?

Comment: esta porción de codigo esta en la linea 57 es dentro del metodo sortController this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({ id: '', }) as MatSortable);

Comment: cuando llamas a la función sortController? no la puedes llamar por ejemplo en el ngOnInit porque todavía no tienes el front cargado y obviamente el sort no existe, llámala en el ngAfterViewInit